# Error When closing IE using Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir-webdriver

I have a Cucumber Test Suite that I'm running and whenever i call the browser.close method it throws the following error

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`open'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in`timeout'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`connect'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in`start'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in`response_for'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in`call'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in`execute'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:200:in `quit'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:59:in`quit'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:168:in `quit'
>     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:136:in`close'
>     from D:/Workspaces/Ruby/RegressionTesting/features/support/env.rb:60:in `block in > '

This only happens when the browser is IE.  Specifically I am testing with IE 11.  This can be recreated by running the following code in IRB

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
@browser.close
```

All of my test scenarios complete just fine, this only happens when I call the browser.close method in at_exit.  This is just simply a nuisance...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Internet Explorer 11 is supported. From [selenium-developers Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/NUZuYb5Aaac):

> IE 11 support continues to be blocked by changes in browser behavior.
>   Workarounds from Microsoft are unlikely to be forthcoming, due to the
>   recent announcement of the in-process development of a
>   Microsoft-authored driver for Internet Explorer 11 and beyond. Note
>   that the Microsoft driver will not be available in any form until the
>   W3C Specification for WebDriver progresses further in the spec
>   process. Furthermore, no timeline for release has been announced by
>   Microsoft, nor should one be expected.

Comment: I have tested this in IE 9 and 10 as well.  This happens in IE 10 and 11 but not in IE 9.  From looking at the notice on Selenium-developers group IE 10 should be supported.